# Java implementation of crypt(3)?

Tags: java, encryption

Could someone point me in the direction of a crypt(3) library for java? One that generates results similar to PHP. e.g.

`james => $1$uAjE75CY$XVIp.DpCuwQTG60h.r5er`/

Thanks

Update:

The password above is separated by $. The 1 represents MD5 (variation). The next token represents the salt used for the hash and the last token represents the MD5 hash. This hash is a variation from MD5 algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

https://github.com/jonabbey/Ganymede/blob/master/src/ganymede/arlut/csd/crypto/MD5Crypt.java

I was able to use it to compare password generated by PHP crypt.

Please notice that this class uses its own MD5 class.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) contains two clasees for Crypt3

- org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt
- org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt

Answer (score 0):

"java crypt" gives several candidates at Google.

Comment: yes, found all those but they are not generating passwords similar to that of php crypt().

Comment: @James Is it a requirement that the generated passwords (Java, PHP) are the same?

Comment: You are aware that most crypt-implementation needs a salt?