# crypt(3) $6$ password hash algorithm (based on SHA-512) in Java?

Tags: java, shadow, sha, crypt, sha512

I'm looking for a Java function to generate/verify password hashes that were encoded in the way `crypt(3)` does when storing them in the Linux "/etc/shadow" file if `sha512` is activated in "/etc/pam.d/common-password".

The plaintext string "geheim" will translate to:

```
"$6$WoC532HB$LagBJ00vAGNGu8p9oeYDOSNZo9vTNTzOgPA.K0bJoiXfbcpj3jBuTkNwdzCrSNadRi8LanH1tH6tGGPPp/Lp3."
```

From http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt I understand that, like with MD5, it's not just a SHA hash like `DigestUtils` or the Java `MessageDigest` classes produce but an algorithm that does a bit more magic.

Comment: Did you check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174943/java-implementation-of-crypt3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found Java implementations for all the new crypt() algorithms here: ftp://ftp.arlut.utexas.edu/java_hashes/

Comment: Meanwhile the Apache Commons Codec project has complete support for all Linux crypt() algorithms!

Comment: I would appreciate a little info about where that link comes from. Downloading random jars can be a bad idea.

Comment: FYI the link is dead, and no `archive.org` version available. Do you have another source?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/commons-codec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Sha2Crypt.java

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on [Apache Commons Codec Digest](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Crypt.html)

Also [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) you may find useful.

In this article [Modular Crypt Format or, a side note about a standard that isn’t](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html) a lot of details of Crypt3 format.

Answer (score 0):

The othe question you refer to only provides links to the traditional crypt(3) method based on DES and the "$1$" method based on MD5. I need to check passwords that use the "$5$" method that is based on SHA-1 or even the "$6$" method that is based on SHA-512.

Based here means that crypt(3) uses e.g. SHA-512 but adds a salt value and does several iterations as described on http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

Comment: After some searching I found at least one implementation of the $6$ mechanism based on SHA-512:
http://tools.arlut.utexas.edu/gash2/doc/javadoc/arlut/csd/crypto/Sha512Crypt.html

Comment: `man 3 crypt` → "NOTES" → "Features in glibc" → `$5$` = SHA-256 (not SHA-1)